# AS3: Call function on exit from Full Screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Using SlideShowPro.  Want to call a function when user exits from Slide Show Pro's Full Screen mode.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/Stage.html#event:resize) could be useful?

Edit - As could [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000150.html)